# $\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}} \otimes \mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}} \subset \mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

The Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$, is defined as the smallest $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^n$ containing the open sets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for its usual topology.

The Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$, is characterized as the set of all subsets $A$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that can be written as $A = B \cup N$, where $B$ is a Borel set and $N$ is a null-set (with respect to the Borel-Lebesgue measure). It is the completion of $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}$ with respect to the Borel-Lebesgue measure : $\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}^n} = \widehat{\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^n}}$.

I know that $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^2} = \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}} \otimes \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$.

I want to show the following (clearly) equivalent assertions :

> - $\mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}} \otimes \mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}} \subset
>    \mathcal{L}_{\mathbb{R}^2}$
> - $\widehat{\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}} \otimes
>    \widehat{\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}} \subset
>    \widehat{\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}^2}}$
> - $\widehat{\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}} \otimes
>    \widehat{\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}} \subset
>    \widehat{\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}} \otimes
>    \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}}$ .

I think that what I need to show is that if $B_1$, $B_2$ are Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $N_1$, $N_2$ null sets of $\mathbb{R}$, then $(B_1 \times N_2) \cup (N_1 \times B_2) \cup (N_1 \times N_2)$ is a null-set of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Thanks.

---

**Edit :**

@G. Sassatelli : Thank you for pointing out [this already existing topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163471/how-to-show-mathcall-mathbbr-otimes-mathcall-mathbbr-subset-ma). Nevertheless, they don't explain there why $(B_1 \times N_2) \cup (N_1 \times B_2) \cup (N_1 \times N_2)$ is a null-set of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So here is my new question :

> Let $B_1$, $B_2$ be Borel sets of $\mathbb{R}$ and $N_1$, $N_2$ be
>   null sets of $\mathbb{R}$.
>
> Why is $(B_1 \times N_2) \cup (N_1 \times B_2) \cup (N_1 \times N_2)$
>   a null-set of $\mathbb{R}^2$ ?

Answer (score 2):

In order to see that 
$$
S=(B_1 \times N_2) \cup (N_1 \times B_2) \cup (N_1 \times N_2)=S_1\cup S_2\cup S_3.$$
is a null-set of $\mathbb R^2$, it suffices to show that if $A$ is a Borel-measurable set and $N$ a null-set, then $A\times N$ is a null-set. This would prove that $S_1$ is a null-set; for $S_2$ it work similarly with switched coordinates and for $S_3$ pick a Borel set $A$ of measure $0$ containing $N_1$.

Since $N$ is a null-set, there exists a Borel-measurable set $N'$ containing $N$ and whose Lebesgue measure is $0$. Therefore, $A\times N\subset A\times N'$, and the latter is a Borel subset of $\mathbb R^2$ of measure zero.