# Question about the proof of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-explanation, borel-sets

$$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}) = \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)$$
To proof this,
$$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)=\sigma\big[(a,b)\times(c,d): a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}\big]$$

and $(a,b)\times(c,d)$ is a set of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$. Hence, $$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)\subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\otimes\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$$

My question is proof of other direction. There is a proof on the *Billingsley's Probability and Measure* and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/163471/how-to-show-mathcall-mathbbr-otimes-mathcall-mathbbr-subset-ma?rq=1). But in the proof of *Billingsley* I can not understand how to he show that $[B : A\times B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^2)]$ is a Borel set.

In the proof of other site, I can not understand the notion of Lebesgue-null set.

Is there any simple proof of my problem?

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is open then $\{A: A\times V \in \mathbb B (R^{2})\}$ is a sigma algebra containing all open sets. (Because $A \times V$ is open when $A$ is open). Hence it contains all Borel sets. This proves that $A \times  V  \in \mathbb B (R^{2})$ whenever $V$ is open. Next fix a Borel set $A$ in $\mathbb R$ and consider $\{B: A\times B \in \mathbb B (R^{2})\}$. This is a sigma algebra which contains all open sets, so it contains all Borel sets. This proves that $A\times V \in \mathbb B (R^{2})$ whenever $A$ and $B$ are Borel sets in $\mathbb R$.

[If you have difficulty in verifying that above two families are sigma algebras I will be glad to help].

Comment: I think in the statement $\{B:A\times V\}$, $V$ would be $B$. Otherwise everything is right and I understand the proof. Thanks.

Comment: @annie_lee Yes, there was a typo.